# How to send Ajax request to different url of same server

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax, get

I am sending an ajax request to my server like this :

```
 var data = '';

  $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: 'api/getnews/home/post/'+title,
      data: data,
      datatype: 'json',
      success: function (data) {
          var obj = JSON.parse(data)[0].fields;
          
          console.log(obj);
      }
      });
```

The url becomes

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/post/api/getnews/home/post/title
> , if I am at
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/home/post

But , I want it to be :

> http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/getnews/home/post/title

Any Suggestion..

Comment: try with this `url: '/api/getnews/home/post/'+title,`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try url

```
window.location.origin + '/api/getnews/home/post/' + title
```

Or

```
'/api/getnews/home/post/' + title
```

like [kusiaga](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6345936/kusiaga)